# Check if n-th child exists, if not create and update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div structure as

```
<div class="hours_logged">
     <div class="time_item">
        <div class="record_id"></div> 
        <div class="time_logged">0</div>
        <div class="desc"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I am adding new items dynamically. When I add new time I save that via AJAX call and update my DOM. The above is the DOM that I want to update. If user adds 2 new times I want to add another "time_item"  DIV and populate values in that. I am already using jquery each function and I get the index number right for the DIV but how do I check like if index is 2 then

```
if(!$('.hours_logged').eq(index))
{
     $('.hours_logged').append(' <div class="time_item">
        <div class="record_id"></div> 
        <div class="time_logged">0</div>
        <div class="desc"></div>
     </div>');
  }
```

Comment: Like this?? http://jsfiddle.net/6FGqN/772/

Comment: `$('.hours_logged').eq(index)` is always valid, even if it has no DOM elements in it, it's still a valid jQuery object.  You need to check `.length` to see how many DOM elements are in a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if($('.hours_logged').length < 1)
{
     $('.hours_logged').append(' <div class="time_item"><div class="record_id"></div><div class="time_logged">0</div><div class="desc"></div></div>');
  }
```

Comment: Ummm, you can't have a multiline string like this in JS so you need to fix that too.